# Why YubiKey (USB key) needs administrator rights (or any other device)

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, windows-11, yubikey

Some time after a clean install of Windows 10 or 11 and using [Yubico keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YubiKey) (USB keys), they need administrator rights to programs to detect it.

It happens randomly, or I don't remember / can't imagine what I have done to the system (installed applications or drivers?).

Using this program from the Yubico forum, *[Administrator rights required to detect YubiKey on Windows](https://forum.yubico.com/viewtopic6671.html?p=6896)*, I got:

> createfile error 5.

It was tested on another PC with the same configuration, and I can access the USB without administrator rights.

Using the latest version of Windows 10/11, with drivers installed, without any antivirus software, and only the default [Windows Defender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Defender).

I want to trace and search for the problem to see if it is a Windows update or another file system permission problem.

I used `sfc /scannow` - but nothing

How can I trace or debug this? Or what can I look for or check?

[image: With administrator rights]

[image: without administrator rights]

[image: Without administrator rights on another PC - same configuration?]

As I decompile what this minisoft looks like, these functions are running:

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute
GetCurrentProcess
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize
GetConsoleWindow
CreateFileW
GetStdHandle
GetLastError
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo
SetConsoleWindowInfo
DeviceIoControl
SetConsoleTitleW
CloseHandle KERNEL32.dll
MoveWindow
GetWindowRect USER32.dll
OpenProcessToken
GetUserNameW
GetTokenInformation ADVAPI32.dll
CM_Get_Device_IDW
SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW
SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList
SetupDiGetClassDevsW
SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces
SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailW
SETUPAPI.dll
NetUserGetInfo
NetApiBufferFree
NETAPI32.dll
```

It looks like the CreateFile function / API call doesn’t have write permissions. To where?

As after disabling the registry key ([UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control))
*Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System*

[EnableLUA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-lua-settings-enablelua) to 0. Then to the first restart, everything works OK. After the restart, the same thing; USB devices are not accessible without administrator rights if I enable [Limited User Account](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-lua-settings-enablelua) (LUA).

Comment: You can try Syinternal ProcessMonitor and check what file access is denied (if the problem is a file access).

Comment: thanks, it can monitor device accessing? from a program?

Comment: Unless using it to login to Windows _(see [Specify Configuration](https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013708460-Yubico-Login-for-Windows-Configuration-Guide) #2)_ or another OS 2FA access requiring Admin rights, this is abnormal, likely having nothing to do with the YubiKey or Yubico software themselves and is more likely a configuration issue/works as expected on the specific PC being used _(especially since it's not replicated on another PC - there are some details being left out, please add them to the question, such as what king of 2FA are you using this for)_.

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ I have two YubiKeys _(5 Nano, 5C, and previously a 4 Nano)_ I've used regularly on Win10 from v17xx - v21H2 and neither requires Admin permissions to access them.  I've installed Yubico Personalization Manager, PIV tool, YubiKey Manager, mainly accessing it via `gpg` \[[Gpg4Win](https://www.gpg4win.org)\]. _(`Sfc` will only fix corruption with system files within `%WinDir%`)_

Comment: @user348246 -Who is the author of YubiKeyDeviceDetect if not YubiKey?  Does this problem extend to multiple YubiKey devices?  You should edit your question to include your information from all the comments you have submitted.  How exactly are you using this Yubikey? Why you are using it might explain what is going on.

Comment: @JW0914 using Yubikey 4 for KeePass mostly, the problem is that, as you can see on the Capture 2 that usb devices are "locked", the system needs admin permission to access them - as you say this is some permision / configuration issue, but for now I havent figure out

Comment: @Ramhound the author of YubiKeyDeviceDetect is dmex, its not Yubikey. I am using Yubikey for KeePass, on the Captures you can see that none of usb devices are accessible (enumerable), from this reason I need admin permission to read them.

Comment: @user348246 I've never used that software - is it required for KeepPass? If not, Yubico has a GUI program to manage the key and create OTPs, otherwise I'd email the developer of that program. Is there perhaps a misunderstanding, as the YubiKey will have two passphrases, a user and admin one, each having a passphrase with a maximum 8 characters. I would install the Yubico GUI program of GPG4Win to manage it via clip [`gpg --card-status`]

Comment: @JW0914 this soft Yubikeydevicedetect as you can see its for debugging, testing, maked by a user. It is not required for KeePass, I searched a resolution for my problem and that was a search result. My key is setupped, now I dont have to use Yubikey Manager or others.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Why are you editing questions and adding content, such as links that didn't previously exist? If an author already linked that's one thing, but content not previously existing shouldn't be added by someone other than the OP _(folks can use a search engine if unfamiliar with a word/device/etc.)_

Answer (score 0):

This issue is addressed in the YubiKey Support article from October 2021
[Troubleshooting "Failed connecting to the YubiKey. Make sure the application has the required permissions." in YubiKey Manager](https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016648939-Troubleshooting-Failed-connecting-to-the-YubiKey-Make-sure-the-application-has-the-required-permissions-in-YubiKey-Manager):

> **You plug in a Security Key by Yubico or a Security Key NFC, but the key is not detected**
>
> Since our Security Keys support FIDO protocols only, and API changes
> in recent versions of Windows 10 have restricted access to FIDO
> protocols so administrator elevation is required, YubiKey Manager
> needs to be run as administrator in order to detect a Security Key.
> This can be done by right-clicking the app's shortcut, and then
> clicking **Run as administrator**.

Try to run the YubiKey Manager as administrator and see if other
apps can now detect the key when running as a non-admin user.

If this does not work, then there is no solution.
Get in touch with YubiKey Support, in the hope that a solution now exists.

Comment: Thanks your answer, but I dont run Yubico applications. I plug in the key and use for 2fa for example: keepass. So the device itself is installed but not accesable without administrator rights.

Comment: Unfortunately your situation is as described above. Try to find out if YubiKey Support have now managed to come up with a firmware update for the key and/or driver that avoids this problem. This is not a problem that you, or us, can solve. It's inherent in changes of Windows 10 that rendered the YubiKey almost unusable, so it's for YubiKey to solve.

Comment: I edited my question, the problem is that, on another computer I can use the key without admin rights, so I got there, when I disable lua (UAC) then I can use the key, but if I enable and make a restart, then to discover the key needs admin rights

Comment: Disabling UAC is not a long-term solution. Have you tried YubiKey Support?

Comment: I know, and for this reason I want to know whats the problem, yes I contacted them, but with no progress...

Comment: Did you open a ticket at [Submit a request](https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/requests/new)?

Comment: yepp, used that page, I feel like one of the drivers is bothering me, and because that the UAC disable the usb devices...

Comment: Yes, it's very likely the YubiKey driver that's the problem. But as it's proprietary, there is not much that can be done about it.

Comment: on an exclusion basis, the yubikey driver is the same on all computers tested, so its not the yubikey driver I think, for now

Comment: The question is if all these computers are identical in Windows 10 version and UAC setting.

Comment: I try to compare settings, but 3 of them are cleanly setupped windows 10 systems

Comment: @user348246 "_I don't run Yubico applications, I plug in the key and use for 2FA, e.g. keepass._" Unless using it to login to Windows/other OS 2FA access requiring Admin rights, this is abnormal, likely having nothing to do with the YubiKey/Yubico software themselves and is more likely a configuration issue on that specific PC since not replicated on another PC. I have two YubiKeys [5 Nano, 5C] I use regularly on Win10 [v17xx - v21H2], neither requires Admin perms to access, and while Yubico PM, PIV, YubiKey Manager are installed, I access it via `gpg` \[[Gpg4Win](https://www.gpg4win.org)\]

Comment: @JW0914 yepp, I used without admin permission, but one day to the next this happened, I dont remember what I have done to the system, but I know that is abnormal, so now I will find out I hope so